# Pandas: map dictionary values on an existing column based on key from another column to replace NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, mapping

I've had a good look and I can't seem to find the answer to this question. I am wanting to replace all NaN values in my Department Code Column of my DataFrame with values from a dictionary, using the Job Number column as the Key matching that of the dictionary. The data can be seen Below: Please note there are many extra columns, these are just the two.)

```
df = 
       Job Number Department Code
    0      3525             403
    1      4555             NaN
    2      5575             407
    3      6515             407
    4      7525             NaN
    5      8535             102
    6      3545             403
    7      7455             102
    8      3365             NaN
    9      8275             403
    10     3185             408

dict = {'4555': '012', '7525': '077', '3365': '034'}
```

What I am hoping the output to look like is:

```
       Job Number Department Code
    0      3525             403
    1      4555             012
    2      5575             407
    3      6515             407
    4      7525             077
    5      8535             102
    6      3545             403
    7      7455             102
    8      3365             034
    9      8275             403
    10     3185             408
```

The two columns are object datatypes and I have tried the replace function which I have used before but that only replaces the value if the key is in the same column.

```
df['Department Code'].replace(dict, inplace=True)
```

This does not replace the NaN values.

I'm sure the answer is very simple and I apologies in advance but i'm just stuck.

(Excuse my poor code display, it's handwritten as not sure how to export code from python to here.)

Comment: I think data are perfect ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better is avoid variable `dict`, because `builtin` (python code word), then use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace matched values with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html), if no match values return `NaN`, so no replacement:

```
d = {'4555': '012', '7525': '077', '3365': '034'}
df['Department Code'] = df['Department Code'].fillna(df['Job Number'].astype(str).map(d))
print (df)
    Job Number Department Code
0         3525             403
1         4555             012
2         5575             407
3         6515             407
4         7525             077
5         8535             102
6         3545             403
7         7455             102
8         3365             034
9         8275             403
10        3185             408
```

Comment: yes sorry the dict name is actually dep_dict, I had just shortened it, I am attempting this method but does not seem to be changing anything. I will try again. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Worked great, my dictionary key was type int which was causing the initial issues, fixed that. Thank you. Also Could you possibly explain the fillna bit, not sure why that works in this case? @jazrael

Answer (score 1):

Or another way is using `set_index` and `fillna`:

```
df['Department Code'] = (df.set_index('Job Number')['Department Code']
                           .fillna(d).values)


print(df)

     Job Number Department Code
0       3525            403
1       4555            012
2       5575            407
3       6515            407
4       7525            077
5       8535            102
6       3545            403
7       7455            102
8       3365            034
9       8275            403
10      3185            408
```